# GLTF format in substance painter exports a huge BIN file

Tags: python, maya, mel, gltf

Whenever we export any textured model as `GL Transmission Format` in Substance Painter it exports a huge BIN file along with GLTF and textures (2Kx2K), where overall folder size will be more than 14 MB.

Is there any way we can reduce the size of the BIN and GLTF files in Substance Painter?

Note: The same 3d model comes around 2 MB of size in Maya.

Comment: Bit hard to guess without the model, or a description of its contents. glTF is a runtime format for use with renderers, so things like NURBS are converted to triangles for efficiency, and that can increase size. If you export the same model from Maya to OBJ, is the size also large?

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Nope, when I convert to .obj the same model comes to 634 kb

Comment: Hm. Ok, yes, you'll need to include the model or a detailed explanation of how it was created to get a useful answer here. There are many possible reasons a file might be be different sizes in different formats.